# How to compare strings in ada 95

Tags: string, if-statement, compare, ada

I'm just starting to learn Ada 95 and I'm having some problems with comparing strings.

Here's the code:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure Test1 is

   vad : String(1..9);
   Amount : Integer;
   Main : Integer;
   Second : Integer;
   Third : Integer;

begin
   Main := 1;
   Second := 0;
   Third := 0;

   Put("What do you want to do?");
   New_Line(1);
   Get(vad);
   New_Line(1);

   if Vad  = "fibonacci" then
      Put("How long do you want the sequence to be");
      New_Line(1);

      Get(Amount);
      New_Line(1);

      Amount := Amount -1;

      for I in 1 .. Amount loop
         Put(Main); 
         New_Line(1);
         --Put(" ");
         Third := Second;
         Second := Main;

         Main := (Second + third);
      end loop;

      New_Line(2);

   elsif Vad = "two" then
      Put("How long do you want the sequence to be?");
      New_Line(1);
      Get(Amount); 
      New_Line(1);
      for U in 1 .. Amount loop
         Put(U * 2);
         Put(", ");
      end loop;

   else
      Put("ok");

   end if;

end Test1;
```

As it is now, the if statement recognises when I type `fibonacci`, but when I type `two` it just goes to the 'else' part of the code.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

What probably confuses you is that the type `String` is actually a **fixed-length** string.

This means that comparing `Vad` with any string, which isn't exactly 9 characters long will fail.

One option is to declare `Vad` and initialise it with the output from `Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line` in one go:

```
Vad : constant String := Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
```

This way you will read exactly what is written until (and not including) the next line-break entered into `Vad`.

Comment: This is the best. But another approach is to compare a substring from Vad : `if Vad(other'range) = other then ...` or `if Vad(1 ..3) = "two" then`

Answer (score 1):

Jacob's explanation is correct. Here's your code modified to use Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line

I removed the "with Ada.Strings.Unbounded" line because the package is not needed.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
with Ada.Command_Line;

procedure Test1 is
   Amount : Integer;
   Main   : Integer := 1;
   Second : Integer := 0;
   Third  : Integer := 0;
begin
   Put_Line("What do you want to do?");

   declare
      vad : constant string := Get_Line;
   begin
      if Vad  = "fibonacci" then
         Put_Line("How long do you want the sequence to be?");
         Get(Amount);
         Amount := Amount -1;

         for I in 1 .. Amount loop
            Put(Main); 
            New_Line;
            --Put(" ");
            Third  := Second;
            Second := Main;
            Main   := (Second + third);
         end loop;
         New_Line(2);

      elsif Vad = "two" then

         Put_Line("How long do you want the sequence to be?");
         Get(Amount); 
         for U in 1 .. Amount loop
            Put(integer'image(U * 2) & ", ");
         end loop;
      else
         Put("ok");
      end if;
   end;
end Test1;
```